# Using a switch based on an enum C#

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I gotta do some homework about creating a farm.
And i have to describe each events within the hours and the days (from 6 A.M to 22 P.M, from Monday to Saturday ).
I'm trying to use a switch based on a enum like this :

```
// this is the hour's enum (day and night).

 [Flags]
    enum Horaire
    {
        Journee =  6 | 7  | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21,    
        Nuit = 22 | 23 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5,

    }
```

In my program.cs, i would like to do a while loop such as :

```
While(Journee!=Nuit)

switch(Journee)

case 6: // for 6.am
Farmer.DoAction();

case 12 : // for 12.pm
Farmer.Eat();
```

and so on until it will reach the night.

Is there an easier way to do this loop without an enum and a switch ?

Thank you.

Comment: Aside from anything else, that enum is *not* a good use of flags. Do you understand that `2 | 4` is the same as 6, for example? Why do you want to use an enum for this at all? Why not just use a single condition?

Comment: It sounds like you want a nested loop, the outer loop with a count of 6 for the days and an inner loop of 16 for the hours.

Comment: Yeah, i think i complicated the whole thing ! thanks for your replies

Answer (score 3):

You can simply create a `Dictionary<int, Action>` that holds your hours as keys and the action to execute in the value:

```
var dayMap = new Dictionary<int, Action> 
{
    { 6, farmer.DoAction },
    { 12, farmer.Eat },
    { 22, farmer.Sleep }
};
```

Than simply execute the delegate by providing the current hour:

```
dict[6]();
```

So you won´t even care on if it is day or night, just pass the current time and you´re gone.

When you also want to consider the weekdays you´ll need a nested dictionary:

```
var weekMap = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, Action>>
{
    { "Monday", new Dictionary<int, Action> { ... }}
};
```

Call it like this:

```
weekMap["Monday"][6]()
```

to execute `farmer.DoAction`.

Comment: that sounds interesting ! Thank you HimbromBeere

Comment: Ok I will try it after the lunch. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You can step through each day and hour of the farmers working week with two simple loops:

```
// Outer loop counts the day, 1 being Monday and 6 being Saturday
for (int day = 1; day <= 6; day++)
{
    // The Inner loop counts working hours from 6AM to 22PM.
    for (int hour = 6; hour <= 22; hour++)
    {
        // Now you can inspect 'day' and 'hour' to see where you are and take action                
    }
}
```

For example he must eat his dinner every day so you can have a case like this:

```
if (hour == 12)
{
    Farmer.Eat();
}
```

He might only plow the fields on a Wednesday at 10AM and not any other day:

```
if (day == 3 && hour == 10)
{
    Farmer.PlowFields();
}
```

You may want to put the switches into a method like so:

```
public void DoWork(Farmer farmer, int day, int hour)
{
    if (hour == 6)
        farmer.WakeUp();

    if (day == 3 && hour == 10)
        farmer.PlowFields();
}
```

Then the inside of your inner loop just becomes:

```
DoWork(farmer, day, hour);
```